# Is the capacitance of two isolated conducting spheres connected to each other by a wire equal to the sum of capacitances of each sphere on its own?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, capacitance

I have a homework problem, in which if I assume that the answer to the question in the title is True, then I get a right answer.

I do not have good arguments why it is true though.

How should I think about this?

Comment: When they are connected , what can you say about the voltage? Work from there.

Comment: It is two capacitors connected in parallel.

Comment: @my2cts: yes, that's good, I have derived a formula which says they are the same, I do not see it intuitively though, only from the formula

Comment: @Farcher: yepp, if I connect two capacitors in parallel, their capacitances add. Why is this a parallel connection though?

Comment: or how can I think of it as a parallel circuit?

Comment: I would not call a metallic sphere a capacitor.

Comment: A sphere is one "plate" and the earth is the other "plate".

Comment: Yep, I think I got it now, it is helpful indeed to think of it like that @Farcher.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to see  it intuitively just charge both toU against earth  the will have a charge of Q1 and Q2 then connect then, they still have U and now together Q1+Q2 . (the capacity of the wire is neglected, otherwise u would diminish a little.